# Angular bootstrap.ui datepicker not popup

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

i'm trying to use angularjs date picker on my project as but seems to be functionality has been broken when i'm integrating date picker to my project

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group ui-datepicker">
        <input type="text"
                class="form-control"
                datepicker-popup="yyyy/MM/dd"
                ng-model="dt"
                is-open="opened"
                max="'2015-06-22'"
                datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
                ng-required="true"
                close-text="Close">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller

```
$scope.dt = new Date();
$scope.open = function ($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    return $scope.opened = true;
};
$scope.dateOptions = {
    'year-format': "'yy'",
    'starting-day': 1
};

$scope.disabled = function (date, mode) {
    return mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
};
```

what am'i missing there?

thanks

here is the [**plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/dfRxrpc5KvuXmLGqaxmP?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You just need  to add `ng-click="open($event)"` to an element, the span for example, and it will work.

http://plnkr.co/edit/bNNrFaeRl6iqFPfa3FMW?p=preview